# R.java wont generate in new project

Tags: android

I decide to create brand new Android project on Linux, but R.java wont even generate, or generate and get remove instantly, also if i place new empty R.java in /gen after clean it get remove.

PLS help i'm broke right now..

Answer (score 0):

Its not R.class Its R.java . Close your eclipse and restart

Then try clean and build your project again

Comment: @Mariusz this is a good idea, eclipse is a bit of a pig to work with, I have found. If the problem persists then it is probably due to a bug in your java code or xml files.

Comment: @Arju u think i didnt do that.? :D

Comment: @D4nC00per U also miss "create brand new Android project"

Answer (score 0):

Do clean/build or run your App.Aso it may so eclipse.If you download your project from internet,it may be caused in about an error in any resources or not compatibility between your manifest and widgets that you used in your layouts or classes.

Comment: u miss "create brand new Android project"